# Selecting Dropdown option, change h1 with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to coding and couldn't find solution **with if condition** for this.

I know how I can do it with html code and options, but this time I need to make it with arrays and if function.

Basically I just need a dropdown with languages (which I made) and then when I click on specific language (for example, English) - I need to change html h1 to "Hello!", when I click Latvian "Labdien" etc.

Basically I need to write a proper if function, hope you could tell me what's wrong there.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select"),
  arr = ["Latvian", "English", "Russian"];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
    txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
  option.appendChild(txt);
  option.setAttribute("value", arr[i]);
  select.insertBefore(option, select.lastChild);
}

if (arr[0] = "Latvian") {
  document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Labdien!";
} else if (arr[1] == "English") {
  document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Hello!";
} else if (arr[2] == "Russian") {
  document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Добрый день!";
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>JavaScript Dropdown</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="heading" id="heading"></h1>
  <select class="drop" id="select"></select>

  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Still figuring out whats wrong with if statement, there is some problem in :

```
if(arr[0] == "Latvian")
else if(arr[1] == "English")
else if(arr[2] == "Russian").
```

Or maybe I need to call a function and then place it onchoice in HTML? Help.. been googling and youtubing all day

Comment: Just fyi, to be super pedantic, one usually refers to it as the if "statement," because it's not actually a "function."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `change` event listener to the select element. Also, you can use the index of each language as the value of the select options, and use the same array when set the `h1` inner HTML:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("select");
var arr = [
    { id: 1, language: 'Latvian', title: 'Labdien!' },
    { id: 2, language: 'English', title: 'Hello!' },
    { id: 3, language: 'Russian', title: 'Добрый день!' }
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
    var txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i].language);
    
    option.appendChild(txt);
    option.setAttribute('value', arr[i].id);
    select.insertBefore(option, select.lastChild);
}

// add a change event listener to handle the language title
select.addEventListener('change', changeHeading);

// trigger a change event in order to display the selected language's title
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

function changeHeading(event) {
    var language = arr.find(
        (language) => language.id === parseInt(event.target.value)
    );

    document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = language.title;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScript Dropdown</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="heading" id="heading"></h1>
    <select class="drop" id="select"></select>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This works if I needed to show the same value (f.e. English) when I click "English". But in this case I want to select "English" and then I need text to show as "Hello!", in Latvian "Labdien!", in Russian "Добрый день!". How to do this with if function?

Comment: @KORENS I just updated the answer. Please note that I changed the `arr` variable to an array of language objects.

Comment: Your option works awesome, but I specifically need to get the same result with if statement... can't find solution online all day heh

Comment: You can do the same check inside the `changeHeading` function: `if (language.language === 'English') // do something`

Comment: @Korens, notice how Mihai's solution doesn't repeat the string literals unnecessarily. I'd use a Map/dictionary, but this solution is just as good. Tell your instructor that how they're forcing you to do this with an `if` is really bad coding.